# Passing multiple ajax parameters to mvc controller

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I can pass a serialized form to a  mvc controller no problems with code below and all is populated

$("#btnExecuteJob").on("click", function (e) {

```
    var frmForm1 = $("#form1").serialize();
    
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "/mvcController/executeJob",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: frmForm1,
        success: function (resp) {},
        error: function (resp) {}
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
  [HttpPost]   
   public ActionResult executeJob(runDetails jobDetails)
   { 
      //
      // Process  
      //


        return View();
     }
```

**I have added a second form to my view and now want to pass both to the controller so I tried**

$("#btnExecuteJob").on("click", function (e) {

```
    var frmForm1 = $("#form1").serialize();
    var frmForm2 = $("#form2").serialize();
    
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: "/jobScheduler/executeJob",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
                jobDetails: frmForm1,
                jobParameters: frmForm2
        },
        success: function (resp) {},
        error: function (resp) {}
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
   public ActionResult executeJob(runDetails jobDetails, runParams jobParameters)
   { 
      //
      // Process  
      //


        return View();
     }
```

and neither  jobDetails or jobParams is  populated,  both work  individually as first example
and all details are populated,  any help much appreciated,
both forms really need to be separate in the controller

Comment: Is this a `.net core` project?

Comment: Hi @Carl,any update about this case?